# Building a symmetric matrix in python from file having 'half' of a NxN matrix data

Tags: python, matrix

I have a data file in .txt format which already has half of the matrix. I want to create full MATRIX.

The data in the file looks like:

[image]

and I want full symmetric matrix like this:

[image]

(of course my actual file is a much bigger 'half' of a NxN matrix so I need a solution other than typing in the values one by one)

I've exhausted all my resources (books and internet) and what I have so far does not really come close. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.  Your task is composed of a lot of straightforward sub-problems (reading lines from a file; splitting a line into terms; making a list of lists; looping over a list by coordinate, etc.), all of which are covered in tutorials and have been answered on SO many times.  Is there something specifically going wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. You fill symmetric elements of matrix similtaneously, by iterating over lines and their elements.

```
with open('mat.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    size = len(lines)
    matrix = np.zeros((size,size))
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        for j, elem in enumerate(line.split()):
            matrix[int(i),int(j)] = matrix[int(j),int(i)] = elem
    print matrix
```